# In Kotlin, is it possible to change delegation at Runtime?

Tags: kotlin

The generated byte code for the below code creates a `private final Base $$delegate_0` field in the `Derived` class. When the mutable field `b` is assigned the original delegate does not change.

Is there a way to change the delegate at runtime while keeping the `zero boilerplate` implementation?

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { println(x) }
}

class Derived(var b: Base) : Base by b

fun main(args: Array) {
    val b = BaseImpl(10)
    val derived = Derived(b)
    derived.print()// prints 10

    derived.b = BaseImpl(20)
    derived.print()// prints 10
}
```

The sample is taken from the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html and edited.

Comment: it's not an answer to your question, but perhaps a solution: although `b` is a val, `derived`  can still be a var. Why not recreate `Derived()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not supported in Kotlin as of version 1.1, but this is under consideration for a future version. This is tracked by [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5870).