# Comparison between Delegation in Java and Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, delegates, delegation

I am trying to understand the inheritance vs delegation fight and how to implement both of them. 
My question is why should I implement delegation the Kotlin way with the by keyword? I think it is one step too much.

Let me give you an example. We have an app with which we can order food. The app is called DeliveryQueen.

**Here is the Java example:**

```
public interface FoodDeliverable {
    void deliverSomeFood();
}

public class PizzaCastle implements FoodDeliverable {
    @Override
    public void deliverSomeFood() {
        System.out.println("deliver the tastiest pizza in the world");
    }
}

public class BurgerCastle implements FoodDeliverable {
    @Override
    public void deliverSomeFood() {
        System.out.println("deliver the tastiest burger in the world");
    }
}

public class DeliveryQueen {
    private FoodDeliverable orderedFood;

    void chooseFood(FoodDeliverable food) {
        this.orderedFood = food;
    }

    void orderSomeFood() {
        this.orderedFood.deliverSomeFood();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome ");

        DeliveryQueen dq = new DeliveryQueen();

        dq.chooseFood(new BurgerCastle());
        dq.orderSomeFood();
    }
}
```

**Kotlin example #1 without explicit use of by keyword:**

```
interface FoodDeliverable {
    fun deliverSomeFood()
}

class PizzaCastle: FoodDeliverable {
    override fun deliverSomeFood() {
        print("deliver the tastiest pizza in the world")
    }
}

class BurgerCastle: FoodDeliverable {
    override fun deliverSomeFood() {
        print("deliver the tastiest burger in the world")
    }
}

class DeliveryQueen {
    private var orderedFood: FoodDeliverable = PizzaCastle()

    fun chooseFood(food: FoodDeliverable) {
        orderedFood = food
    }

    fun orderSomeFood() {
        orderedFood.deliverSomeFood()
    }
}

fun main() {
    println("Hello")

    val dq = DeliveryQueen()
    dq.chooseFood(BurgerCastle())
    dq.orderSomeFood()
}
```

**Kotlin example #2 with explicit use of by keyword:**

```
interface FoodDeliverable {
    fun deliverSomeFood()
}

class PizzaCastle: FoodDeliverable {
    override fun deliverSomeFood() {
        print("deliver the tastiest pizza in the world")
    }
}

class BurgerCastle: FoodDeliverable {
    override fun deliverSomeFood() {
        print("deliver the tastiest burger in the world")
    }
}

class DeliveryQueen(var orderedFood: FoodDeliverable): FoodDeliverable by orderedFood {
    //private var orderedFood: FoodDeliverable = PizzaCastle()

    fun chooseFood(food: FoodDeliverable) {
        orderedFood = food
    }

    fun orderSomeFood() {
        orderedFood.deliverSomeFood()
    }
}

fun main() {
    println("Hello")

    val dq = DeliveryQueen(PizzaCastle())
    dq.chooseFood(BurgerCastle())
    dq.orderSomeFood()
}
```

I think both of my kotlin examples works fine. I cant find any difference. So why should I add FoodDeliverable by orderedFood if it has no advantages? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin example #1** `DeliveryQueen` is not a `FoodDeliverable` because it doesn't implement the interface, so it's not a proper composition implementation. To fix **Kotlin example #1** you have to implement `FoodDeliverable` which will force you to override it's methods:

```
class DeliveryQueen: FoodDeliverable  {
    private var orderedFood: FoodDeliverable = PizzaCastle()

    override fun deliverSomeFood() {
        orderedFood.deliverSomeFood()
    }

    fun chooseFood(food: FoodDeliverable) {
        orderedFood = food
    }

    fun orderSomeFood() {
        orderedFood.deliverSomeFood()
    }

}
```

See how to you have to implement `deliverSomeFood()` even though all it does is that it passes the call to the delegate `orderedFood`? this is where kotlin's delegation with `by` , as in **Kotlin example #2**, comes in, you get the implementation by default and you only `override` methods where need to add additional logic.
The benefit would be more clear when your interface has more methods, in that case delegation with `by` can save you a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't using delegation in quite the way it's normally intended, which is why you're not seeing the benefit.

`DeliveryQueen` forwards its method call to an instance of something implementing `FoodDelivable`, which is the normal pattern; but your case has two important differences:

- it can change that implementation  after creation, and
- the forwarding method (`orderSomeFood()`) isn't the same one that it's forwarding to (`deliverSomeFood()`).

If it weren't for those, you could implement that class with just:

```
class DeliveryQueen(orderedFood: FoodDeliverable): FoodDeliverable by orderedFood
```

…and no body (except for any methods you needed to add or override).

(See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341541/in-kotlin-is-it-possible-to-change-delegation-at-runtime) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054110/how-can-i-delegate-an-implementation-to-a-mutable-property-in-kotlin) for why Kotlin doesn't support changing the delegate at runtime.)

Obviously a toy example like this doesn't demonstrate the benefits of delegation very well.  But imagine if `FoodDeliverable` had many more methods; without Kotlin's support for delegation, `DeliveryQueen` would need a host of boilerplate like:

```
    fun deliverSomeFood() {
        orderedFood.deliverSomeFood()
    }

    fun payDriver(price: BigDecimal, tip: BigDecimal) {
        orderedFood.payDriver(price, tip)
    }

    fun leaveReview(comment: String, stars: NumberOfStars, promptness: EarlyOrLate, foodQuality: QualityMetric): Review {
        return orderedFood.leaveReview(comment, stars, promptness, foodQuality)
    }

    fun <T : ConnectionMethod> contactRestaurant(method: T): Connection<T> {
        return orderedFood.contactRestaurant(method)
    }

    // …and so on…
```

…all of which would need to be kept up-to-date.

(The number of methods can get quite large.  For example, I remember having to write a wrapper in Java for `java.sql.Connection`, which over 50 methods…  Delegation would have saved *significant* amounts of boilerplate!)

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay. I see my issue. Thanks to both of you :)

So let me try to explain it. In Java you have to call the interface method explicitly. So it is necessary that the DeliveryQueen calls deliverSomeFood of the FoodDeliverable.

And if I would have more methods or interfaces with multiple methods, I need to implement a lot of Boilerplate.

Kotlin has the by keyword and that leads to call the interface method directly without the detour?

Hopefully I understand it correctly.